# converting bat file to script file containing java command

Tags: java, shell, jar, batch-file, classpath

I have an java application which contains run.bat file as below:

```
rem set path=D:/Applns/jdk1.5/bin
set classpath=.;lib/derby.jar;lib/mail.jar;lib/activation.jar;lib/commons-codec-1.3.jar
start javaw net.sf.veettukaaran.appclient.ApplicationController
```

when I run this `run.bat` in windows, the application works fine. But I want to run this in `ubuntu 12.04`. So I tried to convert the `run.bat` to `run.sh` as below:

```
# /bin/sh
java -classpath './lib/derby.jar:lib/mail.jar:lib/activation.jar:lib/commons-codec-1.3.jar' net/sf/veettukaaran/appclient/ApplicationController
```

when I run this script by `./run.sh` it gives me class not found exception as below:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.veettukaaran.appclient.ApplicationController
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: net/sf/veettukaaran/appclient/ApplicationControll.  Program will exit.
```

Can somebody please point out what I am doing wrong ? I have checked the path of the specified jar files in `classpath` and class file and it is correct. some other idea what might be wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: your classpath is a little bit different, eg. ./lib/derby.jar vs. .;lib/derby.jar, probably you would like to include the current directory also, so: .:lib/derby.jar.... would be more appropriate.

Comment: Why did you change the dots in the name of the main path to slashes?  Change them back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well I could run run.sh file finally. It looks like below:

```
# /bin/sh
java -cp ':./lib/derby.jar:./lib/mail.jar:./lib/activation.jar:./lib/commons-codec-1.3.jar' net.sf.veettukaaran.appclient.ApplicationController
```

After that I run this command: "`dos2unix run.sh`" and then I run `./run.sh`. and this way application gets executed.

I thnak you all for your responses..

Answer (score 0):

Replace the following

```
java -classpath './lib/derby.jar:lib/mail.jar:lib/activation.jar:lib/commons-codec-1.3.jar' net/sf/veettukaaran/appclient/ApplicationController
```

with

```
java -classpath '.:./lib/derby.jar:lib/mail.jar:lib/activation.jar:lib/commons-codec-1.3.jar' net.sf.veettukaaran.appclient.ApplicationController
```

Notice that I have just added current directory `.` to your `classpath` and corrected the class package name in front of the class by replacing `/` with `.`

Comment: that did not work ! it gives classnotdefined exception and
./runn.sh: line 3: $'\r': command not found
./runn.sh: line 4: $'\r': command not found
"

Comment: These errors are not java errors more of wrong characters issue.